# Can I Have More than One Tenser's Floating Disk?

Tags: dnd-4e, rituals

There is a ritual in the Player's Handbook called Tenser's Floating Disk. I don't see any official errata for it in the UpdatePH document.

It reads:

> You create a slightly concave, circular plane of force that floats a foot off the ground and can carry what you lay upon it. The disk is 3 feet in diameter and 1 inch deep at its center. It remains stationary unless you move more than 5 squares away from it, in which case it moves with your base speed once per round until it is within 5 squares of you. You can command the disk to move up to your speed as a move action. If you are more than 5 squares from the disk for 2 consecutive rounds, the disk disappears, dropping whatever it was carrying. Your Arcana check result determines the maximum load the disk can carry.

It takes 10 minutes, and lasts 24 hours.

I don't see any reason a character couldn't conjure multiple of these. Is there a related rule somewhere I'm missing?

If we can have multiple, then we can carry so much gold out of this dragon cavern. So much gold.

Comment: That last line makes this question exactly that; gold :]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Multiple Disks? Yes!**

[This](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/4ex/20080528a) post from wizards.com is helpful. As long as you have the required components and time to do so, then yes, *get dat lewt with dem disks*. There is nothing in the ritual that says you're limited to one, but you should look at the ritual costs. It appears that the designers were trying to rely on ritual components to limit rituals.

Comment: Nothing in that article appeared to address performing a ritual with a lasting effect multiple times. But it didn't say I couldn't, so 3 million gold here we come...

Comment: So much gold - all served up on platters for all to see...

Comment: As a note to your DM: limitless money never happens. 3 million gold? That may be way too much, even for a dragon.

Comment: @PipperChip Yeah, I'm hoping he doesn't think of that. He told us at the end of last session (after we killed the dragon) that we could get as much gold as we could carry. So I'm figuring out how much we can carry. Just so happens the Warlock has 600g of residuum. Hmmmmm.